# How to access individual files among Multiple files uploaded in Shiny

Tags: r

```
fileInput('file1', 'Choose 1st file to upload:',accept =('.csv','.gz'),multiple = TRUE)
```

Is it proper to use just a single name `file1` for a list of 5 files uploaded in Shiny.

How can I assign names to differentiate multiple files uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload multiple files through `fileInput`, the `input$file1` in your case will be a dataframe where each row is a different file. So `input$file1[[1, 'datapath']]` to be used to retrieve the first file contents, for the second `input$file1[[2, 'datapath']]` and so on . .

## Sample R code

```
# change the index inside read.csv approriately
file1 <- read.csv(input$file1[[1, 'datapath']])
file2 <- read.csv(input$file1[[2, 'datapath']])
```

Hope this helps.